# Does the IDF consider "any fighting age male" to be a combatant?

Tags: israel-hamas-war

[Breaking the Silence](https://www.breakingthesilence.org.il/about/organization) [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_the_Silence_(organization))] is an Israeli NGO that purports to be

> an organization of veteran soldiers who have served in the Israeli military since the start of the Second Intifada and have taken it upon themselves to expose the public to the reality of everyday life in the Occupied Territories.

They say in this [X thread](https://twitter.com/BtSIsrael/status/1739657705931841591)
that the [killing by mistake of three Israeli hostages](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/israeli-troops-killed-hostages-mistaking-their-cries-help-ambush-military-2023-12-28/)  on the 15th of December was caused by the lax rules of engagement followed by the IDF:

> The "deviation from the rules" claim is weak at best. The IDF’s own internal investigation found that the force in question was instructed to shoot at any "fighting age male". No soldier who fought in Gaza in past campaigns would be surprised to learn this.
>
> These instructions are in line with what we know from testimonies of soldiers who took part in previous ground invasions in Gaza. "If it’s a man 15 years or older, like anyone who looks like he could be a combatant, shoot him" one soldier who fought in Gaza in 2014 told us.

Is it true that the instructions given to the IDF soldiers in Gaza are to consider "anybody who could be a combatant" as such and shoot them? If so, do they also count the number of civilians vs. Hamas fighters casualties accordingly?

Comment: The IDF claims that among the casualties in Gaza there are approximately 1/3 Hamas fighter and 2/3 civilians. Looking at the overall population in Gaza this is also consistent with a definition that any male above 15 years is counted as a Hamas fighter.

Comment: Given how little chance got even the escaped Israeli hostages with a white flag it is quite clear they are shooting at anything that moves. Including friendly fire that causes significant part of the IDF casulties.

Comment: @quarague explained in my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, Israel assumes all adult men killed between 18-60 are combatants.

- [According to The Lancet, *"Excess mortality in Gaza: Oct 7–26, 2023"*](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(23)02640-5/fulltext), *"**Children younger than 18 years, women aged 18–59 years, and both men and women aged 60 years or older (groups that probably include few combatants) constituted 68.1% of analysable deaths** (4594/6745; figure B).*" The Lacent was getting it's data from the Palestinian Ministry of Health which "odes not differentiate between combatant and civilian deaths".
- This means (100%-68.1%) = **31.9% of deaths are combatant-aged men.**

Moreover,

- 2024-01-14: The IDF claims 9,000 dead "Hamas operatives and fighters of other terror groups". [source](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/idf-says-it-has-killed-more-than-9000-hamas-operatives-in-gaza-since-start-of-war/)
- 2024-01-24: "United Nations Office for the Coordination of Humanitarian Affairs: Hostilities in the Gaza Strip and Israel | Flash Update #92" claims "23,968 Palestinians were killed in Gaza" [source](https://www.ochaopt.org/content/hostilities-gaza-strip-and-israel-flash-update-92) The UN's source is the Gaza Ministry of Health, which [The Lancet summarized as having *"no evidence of inflated mortality reporting from the Gaza Ministry of Health"*](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(23)02713-7/fulltext)

So the IDF is claiming **37.5% of casualties are "Hamas operatives and fighters"** (9000 claimed / 23968 dead).

In summary,

- The Lancet has shown 31.9% of casualties are combatants-aged men
- Israel claims 37.5% are militants.
- Since the ratio of militants to causalities as claimed by Israel exceeds the ratio of combatant-aged men to casualties, it stands to reason that if you assume the ratio of combatant-aged casualties to casualties as reported by The Lancet is static,

  - Israel claims **every combatant-aged man is a militant**, and further that 5.6% of the militant casualties are women and children.
  - Or, more succinctly, Israel claims that 118% of combatant-aged men are "Hamas operatives and fighters of other terror groups". (`combatant aged casualties = 23986 * 31.9% = 7646 projected combatant aged casualties` and `9000 claimed militants / 7646 projected combatant aged casualties`).
  - Rigorous scrutiny notes:

    - If and only if there are more than 5.7% of child soldiers, elderly (60+) combatants, and female combatants then it is possible that Israel is not claiming every combatant aged male is a militant. But Israel isn't saying that, so  I will assume that it is **NOT** the case, as The Lancet itself assumed "groups that probably include few combatants".
    - The math would be different here if Israel knew there were *more* casualties. But that's not what they say. In fact, they say that there are actually less casualties than the Gaza MoH. From [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/despite-bidens-doubts-humanitarian-agencies-consider-gaza-toll-reliable-2023-10-27/), *"an Israeli military spokesman said this week the Gaza health ministry 'continuously inflates the number of civilian casualties' and 'has been caught lying in the past'"*.

---

### But it's worse,

Also,

- [Gaza is 50% under 18.](https://www.npr.org/2023/10/18/1206897328/half-of-gazas-population-is-under-18-heres-what-that-means-for-the-conflict)
- Of the 50% over 18, only half are men (25%). (statistically true for most populations in the world).
- Of the 25% of men over the age of 18, only a (small) subset is actually Hamas combatants: if for no other reason, then because some subset is disabled, and elderly.

You would expect then for indiscriminate bombing to produce 25% casualties amongst adult aged men (a superset of combatant-aged men). The Lancet has found 31.9% of deaths fitting this criteria. So at best, of the group that be reasonably considered "combatants" one of the world's most sophisticated militaries can only over-represent this group by 7% and assume they're all militants.

Comment: Israel actually claims 39% of those killed are militants (9,000 out of 23,000), which makes your argument slightly stronger. Granted, 23,000 is a Hamas-provided number and not something Israel “acknowledges”, so I’m not sure we can use it as evidence of whom Israel considers a militant.

Comment: Separately from that issue, Hamas is [known to use child soldiers](https://www.newsweek.com/hamas-using-child-soldiers-add-it-their-list-war-crimes-opinion-1859652), so some of the claimed militants killed are likely under 18 years old. That’s a problem with your calculation and undermines your claim that the statistics prove that Israel considers every adult male aged 18-60 a militant.

Comment: @DanRomik I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think your “it stands to reason” inference doesn’t hold up to rigorous scrutiny, but this version of your answer is better.

Comment: @DanRomik I agree. I'll grant it. "rigorous scrutiny note" added if I understand you right. To be clear, I am trying to get your support for this answer. I would love to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for making an effort. I still think the reasoning of your answer is quite shaky. The math is correct, but you're making lots of assumptions to get from the actual facts and IDF statements to a positive answer to "Does the IDF consider any fighting age male to be a combatant?" The issues I see are: 1. Unknown number of child soldiers. 2. Unverified number of total casualties (although that does not seem heavily disputed by anyone, but it's still a number provided by Hamas so should be treated with some skepticism). More significantly: ...

Comment: 3. IDF could well be exaggerating the number of terrorists it reports believing to have killed for propaganda reasons (people will be less upset at Israel if 9000 out of 23000 killed are terrorists, compared to if only, say, 5000 are). So this credit-taking statement for the number of terrorists killed does not seem to me to be strongly indicative of any position regarding how many fighting-age males are terrorists. And also: 4. even if all your assumptions are satisfied, this shows only that IDF considers all fighting-age males _killed so far_ to be terrorists.

Comment: To be clear, I don't have a position about whether the claim in the question is correct or not. The testimony cited by Breaking the Silence is a powerful one and should be taken seriously. And the data you're citing also has some value, but I just think as far as the specific claim being discussed is concerned, the data you cite doesn't do much to address that claim.

Comment: On your first and second claim, The Lacent is world's highest-impact academic journal, and has said that children is a group that "probably includes few combatants". My answer would substantiate the conclusion so long as that group and the others in that proclaimed to include few combatants amounts to fewer than 5.7%. As for the PAMOH number, The Lancet has also published a paper called ["No evidence of inflated mortality reporting from the Gaza Ministry of Health"](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(23)02713-7/fulltext).

Comment: On 3., I think it's certain the IDF is exaggerating the number of terrorists it reports, but that's fine. When it comes to what someone believes, **the most authoritative source is always what that person states as fact.** And so I've taken the most authoritative source as to what the IDF _believes_ which is what the question is over. On 4., this is true. But this qualification would be true for any question on **does $name _considers_ thing**. The consideration is always one of the past when the question was asked. This site can't predict whether a consideration holds in the future.

Comment: There is also one other point on the PA MoH numbers. If in fact the IDF doesn't trust that number, then it would be incumbent on them when communicating a count of dead militants, to also include a count of dead civilians -- which they presumably have and are concealing. In lieu of that number being published, we **must** assume that the PA MoH number is reasonably correct as there is no more accurate and peer reviewed source.

Comment: Thanks. My objections remain, but you’ve done a very good job of explaining the data and assumptions your answer is based on. As for the rest, others can judge what they think.

Comment: The Lancet article notes that there might be *under-reporting* in the mortality numbers, so 37.5% may be higher than the real figure.

Comment: @Caleth I've addressed that explicitly now. While true, Israel claims the Gaza MoH is over representing the casualties not the under-reporting.